# Are Webpack 5 Module Federation micro frontends and Nx monorepos mutually exclusive?

Tags: angular, webpack, architecture, monorepo, webpack-module-federation

I'm investigating `micro frontend` and `monorepo` architecture for an `Angular 12` project. `Webpack 5` recently became production ready and with it, `Module Federation`, Webpack's solution for micro frontends. With Module Federation we have the concept of the shell application or `host`, which houses your microfrontend apps or `remotes`.

I'm also looking into `monorepos` , particularly the great tooling provided by `nx`.

Is `Module Federation` combined with an `nx` monorepo a thing? Or, is there no need for something like `nx` when `Module Federation` already provides me a `shell`  which houses all of my micro frontend apps? As I learn about `Module Federation` it sounds almost like a monorepo itself.

In other words, are `Webpack 5 Module Federation` and `nx monorepos` mutually exclusive or can /should they be used together?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible! The community even has a POC. https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin